# getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() on localhost

Tags: ionic-framework

I get this error in my Ionic app when I run on my localhost with Chrome (`ionic serve`):

```
[Deprecation] getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. 
win @ :8100/plugins/cordova-plugin-geolocation/www/android/geolocation.js:35
```

How to make it disappear ?

How to be sure there's no issue with a device ?

Answer (score 0):

Try again using [this plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) in your browser.

It allows to you request any site with ajax from any source, no matter http/https discrepancies and the like. Practically adds the `Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header in the response.

Please keep in mind that this is a band-aid solution. Your server response has to actually have the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` header, preferably with a more specific value than `*`.

Because switching to HTTPS can be painful or impossible depending on your architecture,
I found a workaround solution: you can use the [Google Maps Geolocation API](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi). Although it has usage limits, it does the job. You will need an browser API key, so don't forget to limit it's usage to your page hostname.

I use it as a fallback method to the `getCurrentPosition()` method if it fails. It allows me to make it work until I switch to HTTPS.

Here's the JSFiddles:

- [HTTP](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro): `getCurrentPosition()` will fail and fall back to the API
- [HTTPS](http://jsfiddle.net/gogs/jwt9f1o3/): `getCurrentPosition()` will succeed

Comment: any idea what I can do next ?

Comment: I still have the plugin and this error at the same on my localhost.  And I don't understand how this appllies to ionic apps, how to switch to https for a hybrid app ?

Comment: Did you use the Google Maps Geolocation API as advised?

Comment: I am not sure how to do this, is there a simple-to-use plugin ?

Comment: No. Programing is hard, I'm sorry.

Comment: haha, good one. I am gonna try and keep my code maintainable with this plugin. I'll write to the guys developing the plugin. Thanks